# Adjusting the height of the webview inside the listview

Tags: c#, string, listview, webview, uwp

I have a listview that contains a webview that contains strings taken from data binding. I want if the webview contains an image, then the height of the webview is adjusted to the height of the image. If it does not contain an image (only text), then the height of the webview is 60.

XAML:

```
<ListView
    Name="ListSingleOption"
    Height="auto"
    Margin="5,0,10,0"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid
                Margin="10,10,10,10"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                Height="auto"
                Background="#FFDFF6EE">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <WebView
                    x:Name="option"
                    Width="auto"
                    Height="auto"
                    Margin="5,5,5,5"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    local:MyProperties.HtmlString="{Binding Name}"
                    DefaultBackgroundColor="Transparent"
                    ScriptNotify="option_ScriptNotify"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</Listview>
```

Code:

```
private List<MyClass> _items;
        string h1= "";
                string urlPath = "....";
                var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(urlPath);
                string jsonText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
    JsonObject questionObject = jsonObject["EXAM_QUESTION"].GetObject();
                string choiceA = questionObject.ContainsKey("choice_a") && questionObject["choice_a"] != null ? questionObject["choice_a"].GetString() : string.Empty;
                h1 = choiceA;
                _items = new List<MyClass>();
                _items.Clear();
                _items.Add(new MyClass() { Name = choiceA });
             ListSingleOption.ItemsSource = _items;

                    private async void option_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
                    {
                        WebView wv = (WebView)sender;
                        if (h1.Contains("height"))
                        {
                            var heightString = await wv.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new[] { "document.body.scrollHeight.toString()" });
                            int height = 0;
                            if (int.TryParse(heightString, out height))
                            {
                                wv.Height = height;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            wv.Height = 60;
                        }
                    }
    
        public class MyClass
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return this.Name;
            }
        }
```

MyProperties.cs

```
class MyProperties
 {
     public static readonly DependencyProperty HtmlStringProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HtmlString", typeof(string), typeof(MyProperties), new PropertyMetadata("", OnHtmlStringChanged));

     public static string GetHtmlString(DependencyObject obj) { return (string)obj.GetValue(HtmlStringProperty); }
     public static void SetHtmlString(DependencyObject obj, string value) { obj.SetValue(HtmlStringProperty, value); }

     private static void OnHtmlStringChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
     {
         WebView wv = d as WebView;
         if (wv != null)
         {
             string option = (string)e.NewValue;
             wv.NavigateToString(option);
         }
     }
```

Example of JSON:

```
{"EXAM_QUESTION":{"choice_a":"<p><img src=\"https:\/\/ujian.study.id\/uploads\/questions\/image\/637ef20551301.jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"200\" height=\"100\" \/><\/p>"}}
```

But from the code above, if the webview contains images, then the height of the webview will not adjust to the size of the image height. How to handle it?

Note:
I've tried using `option_NavigationCompleted` too, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Could you please provide a [mre] to help us further check the problem for you? How to add Listview resource? what is content of `h1`?

Comment: I have edited and completed the code above

Comment: It's strange. In my test, I transfer the content of `option_ScriptNotify` to `option_NavigationCompleted`, and it worked. During your debugging process, is the value of `wv.Height = height;` correct?

Comment: Yes, is it wv.Height = height

Comment: I still can't reproduce your problem. Can you replace `wv.Height = height;` with `wv.Height =120` to see if setting the height directly can be successful. Or when debugging, observe the changes in the Height property of `wv`.

Comment: I have tried changing `wv.Height = 120;` but the height does not change and remains `60`

Comment: Maybe you can try this logic, only call `wv.Height = height` once. https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBEpJ.png